# pandas.to_datetime: which format to choose?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, datetime-format

I have a .csv like that:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
12/30/2002,0930,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.94,571466
```

I want to convert the "Time" column values with pandas.to_datetime module, but I can't find the correct format to use because there's not a separator between hours and minutes.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You should probably mention what you've tried already. Including code. This is a trivial problem that can be solved by reading the appropriate documentation

Comment: @goncalopp I read the documentation with all the available formats, but can't find the proper one because my data doesn't have a separator for hours and minutes. I tried to convert it with pandas.to_datetime module without specifying any format, but it automatically put a generic date together with a completely wrong time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a pass a list of the columns to parse as a complete `datetime` by passing a list of lists to `parse_dates` param:

```
In [6]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t='''"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
12/30/2002,0930,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.94,571466'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[['Date','Time']], keep_date_col=True)
df

Out[6]:
            Date_Time        Date  Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume
0 2002-12-30 09:30:00  12/30/2002  0930  0.94  0.94  0.94   0.94  571466
```

You can see that the `dtypes` are as expected:

```
In [7]:    
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Date_Time    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
Date         1 non-null object
Time         1 non-null object
Open         1 non-null float64
High         1 non-null float64
Low          1 non-null float64
Close        1 non-null float64
Volume       1 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I'm not sure if there's a better way:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

fh = StringIO('''"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
12/30/2002,0930,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.94,571466''')

df = pd.read_csv(fh, dtype={'Time':object})
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

print df
```

Output:

```
         Date  Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume           Timestamp
0  12/30/2002  0930  0.94  0.94  0.94   0.94  571466 2002-12-30 09:30:00
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer --- I did almost the exact same thing

Comment: I don't understand. You are using strings to create a dataframe, but for me, "Date" is an array (column) with thousands of values (rows). How can I put arrays instead of strings inside fh?

Comment: @ilpomo, my `fh` is to replace your csv input file which I don't have. You can just do `df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/csvfile', dtype={'Time':object})`, ...

Comment: Oh thank you! And why do you use dtype={'Time':object}? Do I have to specify the data type for every column?

Comment: If not, `time` will be `int` type (inferred), and `0930` becomes `930`.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell pandas that there is no separator there by specifying the format of the date. `%H%M` tells python that you have a time that has no divider. If you had a divider of `:`, for example, then you would use `format='%H:%M'`.

Assuming you have loaded everything in and your dataframe is loaded in as `df`.

```
from pandas import pandas

# file loading and such

asset['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(asset['Date'])
asset['Time'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(pandas.to_datetime(asset['Time'], format = '%H%M')).time
```

Will give you

```
        Date      Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume
0 2002-12-30  09:30:00  0.94  0.94  0.94   0.94  571466
```

For Python 3 people:

```
df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H%M').dt.time
```

Will give you

```
         Date      Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume
0  12/30/2002  09:30:00  0.94  0.94  0.94   0.94  571466
```

Comment: My code is a little different.

> data loading
asset = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_csv('file_path/%s' %symbol, sep = ',', decimal = '.'))

> column conversion
asset['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(asset['Date'])
asset['Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(asset['Time'], format = '%H%M')

Why do you use .dt.time at the end? If I copy your code the Spyder IDE returns me the error " 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime' ".

Anyway, your code still apply a generic date to my 'Time' column (1900-01-01 09:30:00).

Comment: Ah! I had given you the python 3 solution. I put .dt.time at the end to only take the time and not have the generic date to your 'Time' column. Can you do asset['Time'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(pandas.to_datetime(asset['Time'], format = '%H%M')).time instead? I have updated my solution to have solutions to both python versions too.